# Unwanted autmatic screen lockup

Tags: linux, pdf

My Pc is an Acer Aspire E15. I have installed both Windows and Linux in different partitions. When I use Linux, I can work for 15 minutes (reading PDF ans watching videos). After that the screen is locked automatically. I can't work on my pc anymore until I shutdown. How can I solve the problem?

Ps: I use the PDF reader and the video app provided by Linux.

Comment: Have you used your package manager to update/upgrade all your software?

Comment: Which Linux distribution? By "lock" do you mean the screen saver (but then you should be able to enter a password to continue)? Or is is a system freeze? Did you run any memory tests?

Comment: I update and upgrade all my software regularly.

Comment: It is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS . by "lock" I mean that my computer doesn't respond to any interaction, even when I move the mouse. So I have to shutdown